# condition on a vector of logicals

Tags: r

if I do the following:

```
x <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
if(x) {
    print("hey there")
}
```

`x` is evaluated as `TRUE` because the first element is `TRUE`. I would like the condition to evaluate to `TRUE` only if every element of `x` is TRUE. I think there must be an easy way that I'm missing (I have searched). I thought that `all.equal` would be what I wanted (so I could check that "all elements of `x` are equal to `TRUE`"), but it serves a different purpose.

I know it's not ideal (it doesn't even check to see if `x` is a logical), but the best I've come up with so far is to do something like this:

```
xu_if <- function(x) {
    sum(x) == length(x)
}
if(xu_if(x)) {
    print("hey there")
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`all()` is the function you are looking for

```
x <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
if(all(x)) {
    print("hey there")
}
# >   

x <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
if(all(x)) {
    print("hey there")
}
# [1] "hey there"
```

Comment: +1, also look at any(). Not that any will help you here, but it may be relevant for you for other things like this you're doing.

Comment: @Josh, thank you! I was on the right track with looking at all.equal.

Comment: @nzcoops, thanks for the suggestion. any() will definitely also come in useful in the future.

Comment: @XuWang, you were very close.  One thing that often helps is to check the `See Also` section of the help files.  If you type `?all.equal` and then scroll down to it (near the bottom), you'll see that `all` is mentioned there.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, great tip! I'll remember that.

Answer (score 3):

one line to do the trick

```
print(!any(!x))
```